# Android How to create a View Programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create a view programmatically. The controls(buttons, labels, etc.) and their positions are known only at runtime.

Here I found "Defining a Layout Programmatically": http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-layout/

but I need to be able to draw components at exact locations so LinearLayout, TableLayout etc. doesn't work for me.

How can I do this?

Comment: actually linearlayout's will work fine ... you just have to transform your locations to margins and paddings using linearlayouts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a custom [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html); this allows you to manage placements of each of the children you have (buttons, labels, etc) manually. Check [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA) vid from the google IO event in 2009 titled 'Make your Android UI Fast and Efficient', specifically from about 43 minutes onward for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the Lunar lander example in the android API samples here http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/LunarLander/index.html.  This helped me out tremendously when starting out making games and having to dynamically draw to the screen.